# convert .pptx and .xlsx files to pdf using libreoffice cli

Tags: linux, pdf, libreoffice, converters

I'm using LibreOffice CLI to convert two files I have:

- .XLSX to .PDF;
- .PPTX to .PDF;

To do the task I'm using the below command:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re

args = ['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to',
        'pdf', '--outdir', 'output', 'my_file.pptx']
process = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=25)
re.search('-> (.*?) using filter', process.stdout.decode())
```

It is converting the files to pdf, but unfortunately, it's not keeping the same layout style

[image]

Continuation of the previous page (with the footer) and header of the next page:
[image]

As you can see in the images, the headers have different size and it also has a weird value in the header "*x000a*"

I would like to understand if there are a alternative to fix this kind of problems?

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect a 100% replica of Microsoft Office output from LibreOffice. Anyway, if you think this is a bug, you can report the bug to LibreOffice Bugzilla with a good description and a sample documents to reproduce the bug:
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/

There are faster ways to convert a document to PDF, if you can have a running LibreOffice in the background. For example, see this project which is written in Python:

Python script to automate document conversions using LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org
https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter